# How to get true data from date and time field without doing date and time picker

Tags: android, datetime

I am trying to get date and time value from the user but when ı added the date and time text field , there is nothing about how to write date or time .There are a lot of things on the pager , for date and time data from these text fields.I take these datas and send web service. The fields should look like

```
-/-/- HH:MM:SS
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get you, do you wanna ask user for Time and Date and show it in TextView or EditText ?
and you wanna put a mask on the textView so it appears lik /-/-/- ? 
or you wanna get date and time automatically

EDIT

If it's about only showing the EditText at the beginning with shlashes you can simply do it both ways

XML :

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="----/--/-"
        android:id="@+id/et"/>
```

Java :

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
editText.setText(---/--/-);
```

Comment: no no just get data from user . I will search putting mask will be useful.Is there any way to do with the simple way.Because I don't want to lose performance of program.

Comment: I Edited with the answer

Comment: I want the edit text is shown with seperated blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way :

declare your EditText

and add a TextWatcher

```
TextWatcher tw = new TextWatcher() {
    private String current = "";
    private String ddmmyyyy = "DDMMYYYY";
}
```

when user is typing

```
@Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (!s.toString().equals(current)) {
            String clean = s.toString().replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
            String cleanC = current.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");

            int cl = clean.length();
            int sel = cl;
            for (int i = 2; i <= cl && i < 6; i += 2) {
                sel++;
            }
            //Fix for pressing delete next to a forward slash
            if (clean.equals(cleanC)) sel--;

            if (clean.length() < 8){
               clean = clean + ddmmyyyy.substring(clean.length());
            }else{
               //This part makes sure that when we finish entering numbers
               //the date is correct, fixing it otherwise
               int day  = Integer.parseInt(clean.substring(0,2));
               int mon  = Integer.parseInt(clean.substring(2,4));
               int year = Integer.parseInt(clean.substring(4,8));

               if(mon > 12) mon = 12;
               cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, mon-1);
               day = (day > cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE))? cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE):day;
               year = (year<1900)?1900:(year>2100)?2100:year;
               clean = String.format("%02d%02d%02d",day, mon, year);
            }

            clean = String.format("%s/%s/%s", clean.substring(0, 2),
                clean.substring(2, 4),
                clean.substring(4, 8));
            current = clean;
            date.setText(current);
            date.setSelection(sel < current.length() ? sel : current.length());
        }
    }

 @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
};
```